# Experiment tracking for multiple ML independent models using WandB in a single main evaluation

Tags: machine-learning, mlflow, dvc, wandb, clearml

Can you recommend from your experience about choosing a convenient tracking experiment tool and versioning only "Multi independent models, but one input->multi-models->one output" in order to get single main evaluation and conveniently compare sub-evaluations? see a project example in the diagram.
[image]

I understand and tried to use W&B, MLFlow, DVC, Neptune.ai, DagsHub, TensorBoard for only one model, but I'm not sure one is convenient to use for multi-independent models. I also did not find it in Google for the approximate phrase "ML tracking experiment and management for multi models"

Comment: https://iterative.ai/data-management has some tools and solutions for this in the works. You may want to subscribe to the email list.

Comment: @jorge-orpinel-p%c3%a9rez , I applied through the link with the description of your recommendation, I'm waiting for a response :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm co-founder at Iterative, we are authors of DVC. My response doesn't come from my experience with all the tools mentioned above. I took this as an opportunity to try build a template for this use case in the DVC ecosystem and share this in case it's useful for anyone.

Here is the GitHub repo, I've built (Note: it's a template, not a real ML project, scripts are artificially simplified to show the essence of the multi model evaluation):

[DVC Model Ensemble](https://github.com/shcheklein/ensemble-dvc-template)

I've put together an extensive README with a few videos of CLI, VS Code, Studio tools.

The core part of the repo is this [DVC pipeline](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/pipelines), that "trains" multiple models, collects their metrics, and then runs `evaluation` stage to "reduce" those metrics into the final one.

```yaml
stages:
  train:
    foreach:
      - model-1
      - model-2
    do:
      cmd: python train.py
      wdir: ${item}
      params:
        - params.yaml:
      deps:
      - train.py
      - data
      outs:
      - model.pkl:
          cache: false
      metrics:
      - ../dvclive/${item}/metrics.json:
          cache: false
      plots:
      - ../dvclive/${item}/plots/metrics/acc.tsv:
          cache: false
          x: step
          y: acc
  evaluate:
    cmd: python evaluate.py
    deps: 
    - dvclive
    metrics:
    - evaluation/metrics.json:
        cache: false
```

It describes how to build and connect different things in the project, also makes the project "runnable" and reproducible. It can scale to any number of models (the first `foreach` clause).

Please, let me know if that fits your scenario and/or you have more requirements, happy to learn mode and iterate on it :)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer, I'll answer later about solving my problem :)

Comment: @AlexeyPrikhodko sounds good! :) Looking forward to the questions and some feedback.